# Compiling native C++ module for Node.js, linking to openSSL/libcrypto fails

Tags: c++, node.js, cygwin, openssl, waf

I'm using Cygwin/Windows and I'm trying to build a native module for node.js. I intend to make use of the OpenSSL Library. I have installed openssl from the Cygwin package manager.

I have the following lines in my .cc file:

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>
```

and

```
 DH*    public_dh_key = DH_new();
```

But when I try to link/compile it with `node-waf configure build`, I get:

```
undefined reference to _DH_new
```

**Edit:**

Part of the build script:

```
def build(bld):
  ppp= bld.new_task_gen('cxx', 'shlib', 'node_addon')
  ppp.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-L/usr/lib", "-lssl"]
...
```

(I have tried adding -lcrypto but still get the same result. I have also tried various combinations of "-lssl32","-lssleay32","-llibeay32".)

**Edit**

Output of the build script:

```
$ node-waf configure build
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for node path                   : not found
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local
'configure' finished successfully (0.330s)
Waf: Entering directory `/usr/src/build'
[1/2] cxx: ppp.cc -> build/default/ppp_1.o
[2/2] cxx_link: build/default/ppp_1.o -> build/default/ppp.node build/default/libppp.dll.a
Creating library file: default/libppp.dll.a
default/ppp_1.o:/usr/src/build/../ppp.cc:289: undefined reference to `_HMAC'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/src/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cxx_link ppp_1.o -> ppp.node,libppp.dll.a}
```

**Edit**

I have the header file dh.h in usr/include/openssl

And I have the required files (libssl32.dll, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) in /usr/lib/

**The answer**

jHackTheRipper answered this and got the credit for it, but the final answer is buried in the comments beneath his answer. So to summarise, the waf mantra is

```
obj.lib='crypto'
```

Comment: Can you show some code?  What's the error coming back? Are you checking for `NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect` before sending as depicted in the [api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html#sendToNeighbor())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-lcrypto` should do the trick.
According to the `nm` output on my system `_DH_new` and `_HMAC` seem to be in the `libcrypto` (part of OpenSSL) dynamic library :

```
jhacktheripper@macbook-prolocal:~$ nm /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib | grep _DH_new
0000000000036360 T _DH_new
0000000000036120 T _DH_new_method


jhacktheripper@macbook-prolocal:~$ nm /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib | grep HMAC
0000000000090d40 T _HMAC
0000000000090c80 T _HMAC_CTX_cleanup
0000000000090910 T _HMAC_CTX_init
00000000000908c0 T _HMAC_CTX_set_flags
0000000000090940 T _HMAC_Final
0000000000090cc0 T _HMAC_Init
0000000000090a10 T _HMAC_Init_ex
0000000000090a00 T _HMAC_Update
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to make any difference: 

`["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-L/usr/lib", "-lssl","-lcrypto"]`

Comment: Your log show that you're trying to build a static library `default/libppp.dll.a`, so it needs to have a static equivalent to `libcrypto` in order to build.

Comment: would that be libcrypto.dll.a ? Where should that be? And do I need to modify the build file?

Comment: Yep, that's why I would suggest. If you build openssl on your own, you might be able to build it again statically, so that you'll get all the static .a libraries (`libcrypto.a`). Then you'll have to modify your build file, but I don't know the tool you're using (waf).

Comment: After some googling, you should be able to use libcrypto.a with `obj.uselib` or `obj.uselib_local` options.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, although I have already tried obj.uselib="libcrypto.a" and obj.uselib="libcrypto.dll.a", will try with uselib_local.

Comment: Make sure you have built libcrypto.a before.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1117/discussion-between-tom-and-jhacktheripper)

Comment: I have given you the bounty for your help. However, unfortunately, I still don't have a solution. I have also pretty much run out of ideas now :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to indicate the location of the static library to your tool. But you are not far to get it working in my opinion. I'm pretty sure the official documentation of waf might help you: http://www.freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafbook/index.html#_library_interaction_uselib

Comment: Thanks, great advice: After reading the docs for waf I finally got it to compile! The mantra was `.lib = 'crypto'` Thanks again for your help and encouragement!

Comment: You're welcome. You should post a detailed answer explaining the waf configuration you're now using, and accept it as the right answer. It could be useful for others readers.